SQL on conflict statistics
When running upsert queries in PostreSQL, is it possible to get the on conflict statistics somehow? How much was update and how much was an insert?
I tried adding control columns, but I would like to know if the database might have some feature for that.

Just check the stats from pg_stat_user_tables, you can see the number of inserts, updates, etc.
